# word for "Capturing one's attention by means of a great tragedy"

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a single-word which distinctly means "to captivate the attention in a profound and stupefying way", but such that it would carry a strong connotation of this "captivated attraction" or "calling" being due, very distinctly, to a tragedy.

For example:
"The affixed ears of England were (single-word for suddenly being captivated by some great tragedy) by the King's untimely death."

or for another example: if you had to put the adjoined phrase: "Distraughtly fascinated" in one word.

Comment: Do you really mean _affixed_ ears? They wouldn't be much use if they were detached. (Like Edwin, I was thinking of _transfixed_, but you couldn't really use both words in the same sentence.)

Comment: Most true indeed, but the sentence is rather meaningless to my ultimate question, I wrote it as a display rather then what I need the word distincly for. Thank you most certainly.

Comment: Reminds me of the boy who had his ear nailed to the stocks in Game of Thrones. Be careful not to overwrite and thus distract the reader.

Comment: Do you really want a verb, or will an adjective do?

Comment: @KateBunting: 'affixed' means 'stuck/attached/fasten to something else', i.e. not their own ears, e.g. reindeer ears or whatever, think of the cast of Blackadder wearing fake ears or cow costumes or suchlike.

Comment: Do you mean a reaction due to something you actually directly saw (or heard), or something more remote and abstract, like reading a book that touched you, or sympathizing with a description of someone else's situation?

Answer (score 8):

'Transfix' usually involves (and therefore has a strong connotation of) something horrendous being the cause.

> *She stared at him, transfixed.*
>
> **transfix**: cause (someone) to become motionless with horror, wonder, or astonishment.

[Lexico]

Comment: 'transfixed' usually connotes it's due to something you actually saw (or less likely, heard). But if it was due to, say, reading a book, or sympathizing with something more remote and abstract, 'poignant' would be more fitting.

Answer (score 6):

"Aghast" would seem to express this feeling ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/aghast?q=aghast)).

- The affixed ears of England were aghast at the news of the King's untimely death."

Comment: ***agog*** might be better?

Comment: @WillCrawford On my OALD, this word is not far from "aghast", they are on the same page! To stick to meaning, though, I don't think it worth a comparison; the element concerning tragedy is badly missing; worse, the idea of tragedy needed is contradictory to the idea of excitement that is communicated by  "agog": (SOED) in eager readiness, expectant (OALD) excited and very interested to find something out.

Comment: Absolutely! I thought agog captures the "caught in the headlights" better; but "aghast" isn't bad at all - hence my question mark! You're right.

Answer (score 0):

"Devastated" may work in your example.

> The affixed ears of England were devastated by the King's untimely death
>
> **Devastated**
>
> *emotionally shattered or distraught*
>
> [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/devastated)

Answer (score 0):

A word that equates to an ongoing and specifically *negative* captivation with something is [**horrified**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/horrified):

> [Merriam-Webster: *horrify*]
> horrified, horrifying
>
> **1** : to cause to feel horror
> **2** : to fill with distaste : SHOCK
>
> [*horror*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/horror)
> **1 a** : painful and intense fear, dread, or dismay
> // astonishment giving place to horror on the faces of the people about
> me
> — H. G. Wells

Modifying the example sentence slightly:

> All of England was *horrified* by the King's untimely death.

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.dictionary.com/vocabulary/riveting

> Riveting is an adjective for things that really draw you in, like a book you read in one sitting or a song you turn up so you can hear every lyric. Beautiful scenes are riveting, but terrible and ugly things are also riveting, like the site of an accident you can't stop looking at. Words from a teacher or actor have a riveting effect when they're full of impact and interest, and when you exaggerate a story for your best friend, that's riveting too.